# Add another stroke to the existing canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

How to add another stroke with a different color and length into the same circle?
This script use Mootools lib. Can it be converted in pure JavaScript or jQuery?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xc4xnzcq/1/

Thanks :)

```
// SVG stuff
var ctx = document.id('counter').getContext('2d');
var circ = Math.PI * 2;
var quart = Math.PI / 2;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff00ab';
ctx.lineCap = 'square';
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 10;

var imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 160, 160);

var draw = function(current) {
    ctx.putImageData(imd, 0, 0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(119, 70, 60, -(quart), ((circ) * current) - quart, false);
    ctx.stroke();
}

var myFx = new Fx({
    duration: 5500,
    transition: 'bounce:out',
    onStep: function(step){
        draw(step / 100);
    }
});

myFx.set = function(now){
    var ret = Fx.prototype.set.call(this, now);
    this.fireEvent('step', now);
    return ret;
};

myFx.start(0, 80);
```

Comment: Draw another circle.

Comment: I tried but only the second stroke is visible.
Can you update my fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing a second path seems to work fine for me.

```
// SVG stuff
var ctx = document.id('counter').getContext('2d');
var circ = Math.PI * 2;
var quart = Math.PI / 2;

var imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 160, 160);

var draw = function(current) {
    ctx.putImageData(imd, 0, 0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff00ab';
    ctx.lineCap = 'square';
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.arc(119, 70, 60, -(quart), ((circ) * current) - quart, false);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#bb00bc';
    ctx.lineCap = 'square';
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.arc(119, 70, 60, -(quart), ((circ) * current) - quart, false);
    ctx.stroke();
}

var myFx = new Fx({
    duration: 5500,
    transition: 'bounce:out',
    onStep: function(step){
        draw(step / 100);
    }
});

myFx.set = function(now){
    var ret = Fx.prototype.set.call(this, now);
    this.fireEvent('step', now);
    return ret;
};

myFx.start(0, 80);
```

Comment: But the other stroke needs to be different length, should I create a new function for that? @robert

Comment: If you want, there are lots of different ways you could do that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xc4xnzcq/3/ What about this? I'm using manual values. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: a) you can't really ask more questions in comments (use the Ask Question button to ask a new one if you really need to) b) answers to the question you did ask above would be off topic as primarily opinion based.